# repetition of articles

Tags: adjectives, articles, attributive-nouns

Let's say you have three nouns separated by "or" or "and", and all three are always used together and have the same attibutive noun :

Example:
market force, market strategy and market segmentation

do you have to

1) use the article, and if yes, repeat it for each of them

2) repeat the attributive noun for all three.

More clearly, which alternative is correct:

1) market force, market strategy and market segmentation

2) market force, strategy and segmentation

3) the market force, the market strategy and the market segmentation

4) the market force, strategy and segmentation

Comment: My answer was sent too fast. Your comments were very helpful. Maybe I wll add some more details: the targeted audience does not include laymen, since it is a paper destined to a specialized publication. Moreover, this word combination appears repeatedly in the text (really very often), and for this reason I would like to give priority to brevity and choose 2, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If I were editing this I would not regard any version as absolutely wrong. I would first seek to avoid ambiguity, second consider if the author wanted emphasis, and third seek brevity. 2 and 4 offer brevity and emphasis but it is not clear if the strategy, for example, is only market strategy or some wider and more general strategy. 1 is completely unambiguous and 3 is unambiguous with emphasis given by the three definite articles. In conclusion, I distrust the meaning of 2 and 4, and would chose between 1 and 3 on the basis of any emphasis required by the context.

Comment: Yes. In deciding on the question of clarity, one has to assess how cohesive one's target audience will consider _market strategy_ and _market segmentation_. It's not usually a good idea to separate open compounds in this way, and I'm pretty sure a layman would find the elided version ambiguous. So (1) or (3b) _the market force, market strategy and market segmentation_.